# discord.py custom embed command not responding

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this command, an I wan't it to make a custom embed when I say `p!customembed [colorID] [title] [description]`, but it isn't responding. Can someone help? Thanks.

```py
@client.command()
async def customembed(ctx, color, title, description):
  embed=discord.Embed(title=title, description=description, color=str(color))
  await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colors must be integers or instances of `discord.Colour`, not strings. I'm unsure how you're actually invoking the command, but you can simply use `ColourConverter

```py
async def customembed(ctx, color: discord.Colour, title, description):
```

Thanks to the typehint, discord.py will already convert the color to a `discord.Colour` instance (if possible), there are a couple of ways of invoking the command

- `p!customembed #123321 ...` - hex
- `p!customembed 0x123123 ...` - also hex
- `p!customembed rgb(123, 123, 123) ...` - rgb
- `p!customembed blue` - color name, note that this should be a classmethod of `discord.Colour`

Answer (score 1):

You should post your traceback error logs from the terminal.
But my guess is that your colorID isn't working with the color argument of the embed.

[Embed documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.colour) may resolve your issues